# Getting NullReferenceException right after instantiating object

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I can't understand why the object is null right after I instantiate it. Exception occurs at `_homeViewModel.ApiToken.Token.Id = token.Id;`. _homeViewModel.ApiToken is not null.

```
public class GetTokenInfoCommand : AsyncCommandBase
{
    private HomeViewModel _homeViewModel;
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;

    public GetTokenInfoCommand(HomeViewModel homeViewModel, ITokenService tokenService)
    {
        _homeViewModel = homeViewModel;
        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        var token = await _tokenService.GetTokenInfo(_homeViewModel.ApiKey);
        _homeViewModel.ApiToken.Token = new Token();
        _homeViewModel.ApiToken.Token.Id = token.Id;
    }
}
```

Here's HomeViewModel class:

```
    public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private UserPreferences _userPreferences;

        private ApiToken _apiToken;
        public ApiToken ApiToken
        {
            get => _apiToken ?? new ApiToken();
            set
            {
                _apiToken = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ApiToken));
            }
        }

        public ICommand GetTokenInfoCommand { get; }
        
        public HomeViewModel(UserPreferences userPreferences, ITokenService tokenService)
        {
            _userPreferences = userPreferences;
            _apiKey = _userPreferences.ApiKey;
            
            GetTokenInfoCommand = new GetTokenInfoCommand(this, tokenService);
        }
    }
```

And ApiToken class:

```
    public class ApiToken
    {
        private Token _token;
        public Token Token
        {
            get => _token;
            set
            {
                _token = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The GetTokenInfoCommand is called through a button:
`<Button Content="GO" Command="{Binding GetTokenInfoCommand}"/>`

What may be happening here? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: The `ApiToken` property getter is broken. As long as the backing field is null, it always returns a new ApiToken instance. Setting the Token of one ApiToken has no effect on the next ApiToken returned by the getter. The getter should look like this `get => _apiToken ?? (_apiToken = new ApiToken());`

Comment: That was the problem indeed. Thanks, @Clemens!

Comment: you can further simplify the getter in c#8
get => _apiToken ??= new ApiToken();